Flutter AutoRoute nested navigation moving back and forth between pages
I've been struggling with this for some time now. I am using the Flutter AutoRoute package to handle navigation, and I have an AutoTabsRouter for the bottom navigation bar. I have multiple tabs, each using a "wrapper" that looks like this:
@RoutePage()
class ChatWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AutoRouter();
  }
}

Each wrapper has children that can be accessed. However, I want to be able to push a page from one tab onto another without losing state. Something like this:

Thanks in advance!
I've tried doing it like this:
AutoRouter.of(context).push(
  NavigationHandler(children: [
    ChatWrapper(children: [
      const InboxRoute(),
      ChatRoute(conversationId: conversationId)
    ])
  ]),
);

And like this:
AutoRouter.of(context).push(
  NavigationHandler(children: [
    ChatWrapper(children: [
      ChatRoute(conversationId: conversationId)
    ])
  ]),
);

But in both cases, it loses its initial route and doesn't allow me to go back to the user profile. It seems like I'm missing something fundamental. Any help would be appreciated!
